# Conectar PowerBi con OneDrive

Tags: powerbi

¿Por qué razón al realizar la conexión de mi Power BI a unos archivos que tengo en mi OneDrive no me permite realizar la conexión?

Vale mencionar que dentro de Power Bi voy a "Informes", luego selecciono "Obtener datos", luego selecciono "Otras", elijo "Web": https://nombreempresa-my.sharepoint.com/

Pero no me deja realizar la conexión, vale mencionar que digito bien el correo empresarial, y la contraseña para poder ingresar pero no me ha sido posible.

Answer (score 1):

Sería bueno que indiques a qué tipo de archivo te deseas conectar, ya que no es lo mismo OneDrive que Sharepoint. Si es Sharepoint es posible que necesites conectarte a alguna carpeta o lista de Sharepoint. Para ello debes elegir en "Obtener datos" y escribir "Sharepoint" lo que te mostrará las opciones disponibles:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si te vas a conectar a un sitio de Sharepoint debes incluir la dirección sin las subcarpetas.

También puedes añadir el error que te devuelve Power BI para poder brindarte una respuesta más adecuada.

Comment: Lo que tengo son dos archivos en Excel que los tengo en mi OneDrive, en un segmento de carpetas:
Mis archivos>Archivos Mi nombre>PowerBI>Ocasionales  
ya dentro de mi PowerBi de escritorio, voy al boton del menu "Obtener datos", selecciono Otras, luego voy a la opcion Web, luego le doy la direccion web (Direccion URL, que es la siguiente: https://nombreempresa-y.sharepoint.com/personal/hernan_martinez_nombreempresa_com_co/
y me aparece el siguiente mensaje:
"No hemos podido autenticarle con las credenciales proporcionadas.Vuelva a intentarlo".

Comment: Al parecer es un problema con las credenciales. Además me sigue pareciendo que deseas conectarte a archivos que están en sharepoint porque la URL es un sitio de Sharepoint de tu empresa. Es posible que las credenciales deban ser ingresadas de la forma DOMINIO/usuario y password. Te sugiero validarlo con alguien de IT de tu empresa.